# Correct way to split UTF-8 String

Tags: java, string, utf-8, token

I want to split a utf-8 string.

I have tried the `StringTokenizer` but it fails.

The title should be "0" but it shows as "عُدي_صدّام_حُسين".

```
    String test = "en.m عُدي_صدّام_حُسين 1 0";

    StringTokenizer stringTokenizer = new StringTokenizer(test);
    String code = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
    String title = stringTokenizer.nextToken();
```

[image]
What is the correct way to split a utf-8 string?

Comment: `StringTokenizer` splits on whitespace by default (" \t\n\r\f" to be precise). Why did you expect the second token to be the last part and not the part after first whitespace?

Comment: @JiriTousek I think that's exactly the OP's problem, he expects `0` for title but gets that arabic part instead. Also I tried `.split(" ")` on this string and got the same result (`en.m` for the code, and the arabic string for the title)

Comment: @Rafalon Yes, that is the problem I encounter.

Comment: @AndyTurner well I wouldn't have thought of this, that's both interesting and funny ! I think you should post this as an answer !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem here is that the Arabic text isn't "at the end" of the string.

For example, if I select the contents of the string literal (in Chrome), moving my mouse from left-to-right, it selects the `en.m` first, then selects all of the arabic text, then the `0 1`. The text just looks "at the end" because that's how it is being rendered.

The string, as specified in your Java source code actually *does* have the `عُدي_صدّام_حُسين` as the second token. So, you're splitting it correctly, you're just not splitting what you think you're splitting.

Comment: I would add that using `.split(" ")` directly on your string gives an array in the same order

Comment: The keyword here is [`bi-directional text`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bi-directional_text)

Answer (score 0):

Generally, there is not *the* correct way, but I normally use the method `substring()` of the `String` class (see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)). You can pass it either the begin index to make it return the substring from that index to the original String's end or two bounds of the substring within the original String. With the method `indexOf()` of the same class you can locate a character within the original String if you do not know its index.